# How to create a custom square in a-frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

How can I create a custom square registering a new component in a-frame?

I am trying to update the example found here https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/geometry.md
under the heading "Register a Custom Geometry"

Below is what I have tried - first the js

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry('example', {
      schema: {
        vertices: {
          default: ['-10 10 0', '-10 -10 0', '10 -10 0', '10 -10 0'], //added a 4th set of dimensions here
        }
      },

      init: function (data) {
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices = data.vertices.map(function (vertex) {
            var points = vertex.split(' ').map(function(x){return parseInt(x);});
            return new THREE.Vector3(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]); //added a 4th 'points' here
        });
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2, 3)); //added a 4th number here
        geometry.mergeVertices();
        geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        this.geometry = geometry;
      }
    });
```

I have made comments where I have made changes, essentially just adding 4 elements where there were previously three

I then add this into the html

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: example; vertices: 1 1 -3, 3 1 -3, 2 2 -3, 1 2 -3"></a-entity>
```

But it seems to just ignore my new vertice and just creates a triangle. I suspect there is something about the three.js code that I do not understand and I don't seem to be able to solve it by looking at their documentation - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding the 4th number in vector3? Where does it go?

Comment: Do you mean vector3 only creates triangles? what should I put for a square vector4?I have not used three.js before sorry

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Comment: vector3 creates 3 numbers and gives you some methods you can use on them. `Vector4` creates 4 numbers, while `Vector2` creates 2. These have nothing to do with triangles.

Comment: `Face3( a, b, c, normal, color, materialIndex )` is the signature. Your fourth `Vector3` there would define the normal, not make a triangle into two triangles.

Comment: ok, thank you - what is the signature to make a shape that connects the 4 numbers I would create with Vector4?

Comment: I think it's more involved than that. I'm not sure what kind of advice to give you here. This is the problem with a-frame I believe. It may not be enough to just get familiar with a library - three.js in this case since you obviously tried to do something against the documentation. I'd brush up on javascript, and then study three.js a bit.

Comment: ok thanks your comments have helped me, in essence I create 2 triangles with face3. I have got it working, I will post my solution here but please do vote it down/comment if it is incorrect

Comment: As I understand it the example you have followed is for a triangle - to create a triangle you define 3 vertices (corners) which together create 1 face (faces are always triangles defined by the index of the vertex so '0 1 2'). 
To define a square you would need to define 4 vertices (corners) then 2 faces. face 1 might be verts '0 1 2' and face 2 might be verts '1 3 2'

Comment: Thanks Thomas, yes I think that is where I got to, I have posted my solution below, it would be great if you could have a look and tell me if I have done it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work;

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry('example', {
      schema: {
        vertices: {
          default: ['-10 10 0', '-10 -10 0', '10 -10 0', '10 -10 0'],
        }
      },

      init: function (data) {
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices = data.vertices.map(function (vertex) {
            var points = vertex.split(' ').map(function(x){return parseInt(x);});
            return new THREE.Vector3(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
        });
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3));
        geometry.mergeVertices();
        geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        this.geometry = geometry;
      }
    });
```

again followed by this in the html

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: example; vertices: 1 1 -3, 3 1 -3, 2 2 -3, 1 2 -3"></a-entity>
```

Comment: a Vector3 only has 3 components x,y and z https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3
You could consider replacing your custom 'split' logic with the aframe utils coordinates.parse method to convert string coords to objects then just use the result of that to construct the Vector3's.

Comment: This seems fine. It's still pretty low level, i'd advise experimenting a bit with three.js and learning a bit about what is "indexed geometry" for example.

Comment: Why dont you start with `THREE.PlaneGeometry` and modify the vertices?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that

Comment: hey is it possible to manipulate the vertices on the go? in an animation loop?

Comment: There seem to be an issue with`THREE.Face3`