# How can I create a custom 3d shape in a frame?

Tags: geometry, components, aframe

Following this example in [How to create a custom square in a-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663216/how-to-create-a-custom-square-in-a-frame), I tried creating a tetrahedron with the vertices and faces found in a blender-obj-export.

Here's my code :

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerGeometry('example', {
  schema: {
    vertices: {
      default: [],
    }
  },

  init: function (data) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices = data.vertices.map(function (vertex) {
      var points = vertex.split(' ').map(function(x){return parseInt(x);});
      return new THREE.Vector3(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
    });
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,2,3));
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,3,1));
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1,3,2));
    geometry.mergeVertices();
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    this.geometry = geometry;
  }
});
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity geometry="primitive: example; vertices:
    0 1 0,
    0.94 -0.33 0,
    -0.47 -0.33 -0.82,
    -0.47 -0.33 0.82
  "></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Here is a code pen : https://codepen.io/trufo/pen/rNaxgPr

With the vertices and faces from the original example I see a square, everything is ok, but when I change those values to get my tetrahedron, nothing appears. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `parseInt` for floating point values (0.4, -0.82, etc.). Most of them are rounded to 0, so most vertices are `(0, 0, 0)` - therefore the geometry have no faces.

Changing `parseInt` to `parseFloat` solves the issue - check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt41ahnx/4/).

Comment: @MikeyMuss - glad i could help !