# Aframe create shape from vectors

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm doing something like this, [How to create a custom square in a-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663216/how-to-create-a-custom-square-in-a-frame) but with custom shapes (i.e. drawing around an image to make a hotspot to make part of that image interactive)

I've got the line working and I'm now trying to convert this into a fill.

```
    this._mesh = make('a-plane', {
        geometry:"buffer: false"
    }, this.el)
    this._mesh.addEventListener('loaded', e => {
        this._mesh.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.vertices = this._points
        this._mesh.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.computeFaceNormals()
        this._mesh.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.computeVertexNormals()
    })
```

I'm getting close but it's only showing one triangle i.e. something like this [image]

How do i get the shape to fill the whole area?  I have done this before with a ConvexGeometry and Quick hull but it seems cumbersome.

I got the idea for updating the vertices of a plane from the above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an array with `Vector2` objects representing the contour of your shape in CCW order, you can use an instance of `Shape` and `ShapeBufferGeometry` to achieve the intended result. Just pass the array of points to the ctor of `Shape`. The following official `three.js` example demonstrates this approach:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes

BTW: Instead of defining the contour by an array of points, you can also use the API of `Shape` to define shapes. A simple triangle would look like so:

```
var triangleShape = new THREE.Shape()
    .moveTo( 80, 20 )
    .lineTo( 40, 80 )
    .lineTo( 120, 80 )
    .lineTo( 80, 20 );

var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

`three.js R113`

Comment: Thanks @mugen87, the points I have are Vector3, I'm wondering if there is an easy way to put them on a plane do something like this to create the shape. What is 'the ctor of Shape'?  Could you demostrate what you mean?

Comment: The idea is to assign an array of points to the constructor of `Shape` like so: `var triangleShape = new THREE.Shape( myArrayOfPoints );`

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87, I see the constructor is an array of Vector2s, where my points are all Vector3s. I might try this again with a 2D plane in scene and capture the points from the intersections in that. I've reverted to your very useful ConvexHull for now.